# Error when removing random item from list

Tags: python, list, random

I'm getting an error when I try to run this that says:

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

This error, however, does not always occur. I think that is because it only happens when the random number that comes back has already been removed but I don't know for sure or how to fix it. All help greatly appreciated.

```
def main():
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,]
    count = 0

    while count <= 3:  #how many numbers to remove
        count += 1
        remove(numbers)

print (numbers)
done = input ("Enter to exit.")

def remove(numbers):

    import random
    randnum = random.randint(1,10)
    numbers.remove(int(randnum))


main()
```

Comment: But you repeat the experiment. If you remove `5` from the list, **you cannot remove it a second time**...

Comment: Yes that is what I said I thought might be happening, I just don't know how to prevent it or change to make it work. I am still somewhat new to programming so I hope it is not something simple that I just missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until you get a number that is `in` the list:

```
def remove(numbers):
    import random
    randnum = random.randint(1, 10)
    while randnum not in numbers:
        randnum = random.randint(1, 10)
    numbers.remove(randnum)
```

You can also use `random.choice` (thanks @WillemVanOnsem) and pick an element that you know exists:

```
def remove(numbers):
    import random
    numbers.remove(random.choice(numbers))
```

Comment: Why not use `choice`?

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe the problem here is two fold.   (1) that the random number you are generating is greater than the current list after removing a few items and (2) python lists are zero based.

So, for the first problem, it you have already removed 2 items previously and the random number generator creates 9, the 9 position will no longer be there.   So, you need to generate the random number based on the current length of the list:

`randnum = random.randint(0,len(numbers) -1)`

This should guarantee that the random number is in the list and should be available.

For the second problem, there is a zero position (the first position on the array) that needs to be taken into account.   So, if you have ten positions in the python list, the indexes for those positions would be 0 through 9, NOT 1 through 10.  So when you try to remove position 10, it does not exist.   Start your random number generator at 0 (as shown above) and end it at one less than the length.   That should cover all possible positions in the list.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete one item two times. It's not exist.

Meybe use Try: except: statement.

Comment: But this will not **always** remove an item when you call the method.